# Regex in PHP doesn't work

Tags: php, regex

```
       $subject= "Citation flow <img src='/static/images/icons/help.png'>
                                </span>
                            </p>
                            <p style='font-size: 150%;'><b>11</b></p>";
           $pattern="/Citation flow[.]+<b>([0-9]+)<\/b>/i";

          preg_match_all($pattern, $subject,$matches,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

          print_r($matches);
```

I want to capture the number 11 inisde the bold tags.. but my regex expression doesnt work.. why?

UPDATE:

I came up with this.. but I am not 100% it is the best solution:

```
$pattern="/Citation flow[\s\S]*<b>([0-9]+)<\/b>/i";
```

Comment: When you say `[.]+` you actually mean `.+`. `[.]+` matches a string of dots; the dot is not special inside a character class.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using an actual HTML parser, like simpledom - http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/.

Comment: You seem to be trying to parse HTML with regular expressions. You may want to read http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/110707

Comment: I know about simple_html_parse.. but the doc I am trying to scrape hasnt got many unique tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it cannot match as `Citation flow` has a space after it, not an arbitrary number of dots. You probably meant

```
(?si)Citation flow.+<b>(\d+)</b>
```

Comment: whats the difference between \d+ and what i did

Comment: Don't forget to use `/s` or `(?s)`.

Comment: Dmitry: `\d` is a shorthand for `[0-9]`.

Comment: You can put the `s` and `i` options after the trailing delimiter in `preg_match`. It's just a way of specifying regex options inline.

Answer (score 0):

Do you not want

```
$pattern="/Citation flow[.]+<b>([0-9]+)<\/b>/si";
```

Comment: Unlikely, as that would also try matching literal dots.